# python ffvideo , 'libavutil/rational.h' file not found

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg

I currently have a problem while installing an `ffvideo (0.0.13)` app to a django project. I use `zc.buildout` and simply get fatal error's while building:

> - 'libavutil/rational.h' file not found

My System is running on `OSX 10.10`, I tried to install `ffmpeg-dev` via `macport`.

The lib is at `/opt/local/include/libavutil/`

Anyone got an idea or knows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

install newer ffmpeg library, I'm personally using `brew`

ffvideo is quite old and not touch for the last few years, maybe look at the [PyAV](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV) - which looks much better.